# Processing Particle Sprites

Tags: processing, particles

I am trying to copy particles from an image onto a sprite square that falls to the bottom of the screen for a homework assignment. The part I am having the most trouble with is copying the pixels from my background image to my sprite. I'm not really sure how to start but I know I should include things like

```java
for (int x=0; x< img.width; x++)
  {
    for (int y=0; x< img.height; y++)
    {
      int loc = x + y*img.width;
      ...
    }
 }
```

and

```java
PImage.pixel[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial on images in Processing available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/images.html).

Using a nested `for` loop to iterate over the pixels in the image is a good start. From there you need to use the `get()` function in the `PImage` class to get the color at a particular pixel. Then you can use the `set()` function to set the pixels of the target image or `PGraphics`.

More info is available in [the Processing reference](https://processing.org/reference/PImage.html).